# How can I add lines in /etc/rc.conf?

Tags: command-line, freebsd

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.banym.de/freebsd/install-freebsd-11-on-thinkpad-t420) to install FreeBSD 10.1 and at the step where it says "Add the following lines to `/etc/rc.conf`" I must to add the following lines in there:

```
hald_enable="YES"
dbus_enable="YES"
performance_cx_lowest="Cmax"
economy_cx_lowest="Cmax"
```

But I'm new in Unix and I don't know how to add these lines in `/etc/rc.conf`, I tried with `cd` but it says `Too much arguments`. How can I add these lines in the `/etc/rc.conf`?

EDIT: I didn't installed yet a desktop environment.

Comment: I need to ask: What made you try `cd`?

Comment: That was the first thing that came in my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ***need*** to learn some sort of text editor. There are several available for FreeBSD like nano, ed, vi, emacs, and many others. I don't want to start a flame war so I'll encourage you to learn them on your own.

If you want to get the really quick and dirty way to acomplish what your asking try:

```
cat >> /etc/rc.conf << "EOF"

dbus_enable="YES"

performance_cx_lowest="Cmax"

economy_cx_lowest="Cmax"
EOF
```

Comment: That's complicated for a beginner. You can do `echo 'hald_enable="YES"' >> file` to append a line to a file. And I fully agree: you need to learn how to use an editor.

Comment: @Marki oops...forgot to change it back to `/etc/rc.conf` Now the asker just needs to copy and paste as root.

Comment: There is an easy editor on FreeBSD called `ee`.

Comment: Regarding the `ee` editor… [Described in the Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/editors.html). See [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ee&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports).

Answer (score 5):

There is a dedicated utility called `sysrc`, which should be already installed on your FreeBSD. For example:

```
sysrc hald_enable=YES
```

Here's a one-liner:

```
sysrc hald_enable=YES dbus_enable=YES performance_cx_lowest="Cmax" economy_cx_lowest="Cmax"
```

See [`man 8 sysrc`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sysrc) for more details.

Alternatively, for services one can use [`service(8)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?service) to enable a service on FreeBSD 13.0 or later:

```
service sshd enable
```

See [rc.subr(8)](http://man.freebsd.org/rc.subr) on your system to figure out if the `enable` command is supported by services on your system.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Editing files by hand is evil.

It's error prone, it's not script-friendly, and scripting may not achieve the same idempotence.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be..

```
echo "hald_enable="YES"
dbus_enable="YES"
performance_cx_lowest="Cmax"
economy_cx_lowest="Cmax"" >> /etc/rc.conf
```

Comment: You have to use single quotes around expression, that contains double quotes.

Comment: Nope, tried it myself.

Comment: And did the result contain the double quotes as specified in the question?